# Is there a way find edits that you've reviewed?

Tags: support, review, suggested-edits

I've now just reached the point where I'm able to review suggested edits, and have reviewed a handful. I've also just rejected an edit for the first time. (The edit inserted extra information which the questioner was assumed to have intended, and which changed the kind of answer needed. If the questioner didn't intend the extra information, answers would have needed to explain why it mattered.)

Being new to reviewing edits, I'd find it useful to check afterwards what the other reviewer did.

With approved edits this is fairly easy—the post gets bumped and is easy to find.

Short of searching for posts by their content, is there an easy way to find edits one has rejected?

Comment: The way I navigate to my recent reviews from my user Activity page is: 1) click on "all actions", 2) click on "reviews" submenu.

Comment: @hardmath I should probably just remember that "all actions" is the place to find anything I can't find anywhere else!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

All your reviews are on your user-page see

https://math.stackexchange.com/users/current?tab=activity&sort=reviews

Alternatively you can consult the "history" of the relevant review queue (exists for each queue):

https://math.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/history

There is a switch to see "all items" or "only your items" (the former is not available to all users, access is a separate privilege).

To see how the review played out in detail,  click on the "reject" (not the question title) to get to the review summary that tells you exactly what happened.

Comment: Thsnks—I'd looked on the page but in the wrong place. No edut had gone through and I rejected it 45 minutes ago, so I assume someone else has also rejected it.

Comment: Clicking on the "reject" (not the question title) you get to the review summary that tells you exactly what happened.

Comment: Ah now that's exactly what I was after. I now know that the first reviewer accepted it, I rejected it with a message, and the third reviewer rejected it with the standard message.